# Feeding the output back to input in 3D CNN model

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, training, recurrent-neural-networks, pytorch

I am currently designing a Model which takes Input 3D Grid and Model Output at $t-1$. The model figure is described below

[image]

I have two thoughts in training the model for above situation.

- Feed output $t-1$ from ground truth with some noise. And, during testing feed output of the model as previous output at $t-1$. Maybe we can fine tune with model output when training loss is sufficiently low.
- Feed model output to next stage as $t-1$ output. But I am not sure if this works.

The situation is similar to RNNs but I am using 3D CNN’s here. I don’t know if RNN can be used here. How can I train such a model.

Comment: What is the word looking like **shoref** in between the two 3D-Encoders?

Comment: Sorry, It is "shared" not shoref. My bad. These are shared convolutions.